# Which delegate method will get fired in UITextfield or UITextview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to know which delegate method will get fired when we long press the UITextfield or UITextview to move the cursor? Please help me out.

Comment: You've been asking iOS questions on SO long enough to be able to read the documentation and see that there is no delegate call here unless you set one up.

Comment: Is there any delegate getting called when moving the cursor in textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Gesture Recognizer for this purpose

1)Firstly Add Recognizer to your TextFiled

```
**-(void)viewDidLoad{**

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizerTextFiled = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandlerGurmukhiFirstSearch:)];

    recognizerTextFiled.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;

    //after this time Recognizer will invoke   

    // here i have added the Recognizer to that textField

    // myTextFiled is a textField at which we want to detect the cursor movement

     [myTextFiled addGestureRecognizer:recognizerTextFiled];

     [recognizerTextFiled release];      
    }
```

**2) You may Write Your Logic after detecting the Cursor Movement As Below**

```
**-(void)longPressHandlerGurmukhiFirstSearch:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer**
 {           
       if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ==gestureRecognizer.state)
         {
  // you can write the code here as you want for moving the Cursor
        }

if(UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == gestureRecognizer.state) {
            // Do repeated work here (repeats continuously) while finger is down
      }

  if(UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == gestureRecognizer.state) {
            // Do end work here when finger is lifted
        }
    }
}
```

I Hope This would help you to detecting the cursor movement over **UITextField**

Answer (score 1):

There is no suitable UITextField delegate for detecting cursor movements.

You may be able to use `textViewDidChangeSelection:` when working with a UITextView, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChangeSelection%3a).